# JPA querying with CriteriaBuilder IN

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

It's my first time posting here asking for help, and sorry if it is a very stupid thing, but i've tried some codes that i found but it's no working at all.

On our application we were using a single string to filter the status, but the new requirements needs to change this to a List the constraint here is that we are trying to use the old method for backwards compatibility and make more easy to our FE to integrate with us.

My question is, it's possible to using the criteriaBuilder.in() to filter that using the List?

Here I post the specification that is in our BE.

```
    public Page<ReturnObject> findAll(final Pageable pageable, final GetRequest request) {
        final Specification<ReturnObject> specification =
                Specification.where(ReturnObjectSpecs.getFeNameSpec(request.getFeName())
                        .and(ReturnObjectSpecs.getIdSpec(request.getId()))
                        .and(ReturnObjectSpecs.getUserIdSpec(request.getUserId()))
                        .and(ReturnObjectSpecs.getStatusSpec(request.getStatus())));

        return sessionRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
    }
```

Here it goes the previous spec for criteriaBuilder

```
    static Specification<ReturnObject> getStatusSpec(final String status){
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> StringUtils.isEmpty(status)?
                criteriaBuilder.isTrue(criteriaBuilder.literal(true)):
                criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("status"), status);
    }
```

Here goes that i've tried in order to query with that list.

```
    static Specification<ReturnObject> getStatusSpec(final List<String> status) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            if (status.isEmpty()) {
                return criteriaBuilder.isTrue(criteriaBuilder.literal(true));
            } else {
                Expression<String> expression = root.get("status");
                expression.in(status);
                return criteriaBuilder.in(expression);
            }
        };
    }
```

Here is the actual model that we have

```
public class GetRequest {
    private Long id;
    private Long userId;
    private List<String> status;

    //Getters and setters are ignored 
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work properly:

```java
return root.get("status").in(status)
```

**Offtopic**

```java
criteriaBuilder.isTrue(criteriaBuilder.literal(true))
```

can be replaced with

```java
criteriaBuilder.and()
```

as per [CriteriaBuilder#and](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#and-javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...-)

> Create a conjunction of the given restriction predicates. **A conjunction of zero predicates is true.**